# send xml from java to C# via tcp socket

Tags: java, c#, xml, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to Generate the XML in Client Side(Java) and send that XML to Server (C#).

- The generated XML can include Files, String messages, etc...

My Problem,

- How to **generate** XML , **write** to it and send through a Socket in Java(Client).
- How to **receive** XML through a Socket and **Read** it in C#(Server).

Comment: can you share what you are able to achieve so far?

Comment: I also have like your situation. I use `ActiveMQ` and `JMS`. `java` publish the message to `ActiveMQ` jms server, `C#` program get the message form the server. Both of `Publisher` and `Receiver` must have data agreement. Which is use `TCP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation it will be better to binary serialize the generated XML and sent it over TCP.
Now, lets go through your questions:

1. How to generate XML , write to it : Use javax.xml package for XML related transformations and binary serialize it.
2. Send through a Socket in Java(Client): Use java.net package for writing over TCP.
3. How to receive XML through a Socket and Read it in C# : You can get ByteStream, convert it to String and use XMLDocument.LoadXml(String) to get the XML.